# How do I select one background from multiple and make that background show up on a different web page?

Tags: html

I have an html page with a button saying "background." When I click on that button, I am taken to a page saying "choose background" with a bunch of images on it. The user is supposed to scroll through the images, find one they like, and click on it, taking them back to the original page with the button saying background, except this time with the very background they chose in the center of the page.

How do I do this? I want to use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

This first file is part of `design.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styledesign.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="header">Design Mode</h1>
  <img src="./imagesdesign/purplewaterfall.png" alt "A purple waterfall" id="waterfall">
  <ul id="rightlist">
    <li id="backgroundli"><a href="../backgroundpage/background.html" target="_blank">Background</a></li>
  </ul>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scriptdesign.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

The second file is `background.html`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylebackground.css">
    <title>Background | Virtual Reality Safe Space</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Choose Background</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="beach.png" alt="beach"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="bedroom.png" alt="bedroom"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="fallcolors.png" alt="fall colors"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="icywaterfall.png" alt="icy waterfall"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="moonlight.png" alt="moonlight"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="park.png" alt="park"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="purplewaterfall.png" alt="purple waterfall"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="smalltown.png" alt="small town"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="stable.png" alt="stable"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="sunrise.png" alt="sunrise"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="sunsetbeach.png" alt="sunset beach"></a></li>
      <li><a href="../designpage/design.html"><img src="texturedroom.png" alt="textured room"></a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77673537/edit) to include your code so we can help you make it work properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I have two ideas (1) `background.html` should have links with parameter `../designpage/design.html?image=texturedroom.png` and `design.html` should get this value and use it to display image. But this method is popular when you run web server with `PHP`, `Ruby`, `Python`, `CGI` and code on server can get parameter and generate HTML with this image. (2) `background.html` should use `JavaScript` to add `texturedroom.png` to `cookies` and `design.html` should use `JavaScript` to check if there is information in `cookies` and use it to add image on page.

Comment: I like your first idea. If I used cookies, I wouldn't be able to associate the background chosen with the person's account. How do I execute idea 1? Also, what do you mean by "should have links...to display image"?